# Batch File how to run all files in folder

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I am trying to find a batch file command that will allow me to run all .lnk or .html files with in a folder. I tried using the wildcards (*.lnk) but this wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon further comments, this should help - you don't need recursion to process a single folder, and this will handle long filenames.

```
@echo off
for %%v in ("C:\Users\username\Desktop\Test\*.lnk") do start "" "%%~v"
```

It will open every .lnk file in the folder.

Comment: This could be easily modified to a different path or to start a different extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

for /r %%v in (*.lnk) do start %%v

Note:

Don't put spaces on shortcut filenames.

Comment: I tried to run this and it won't open the .lnk file Here is the code I am using.

for /r %%v in (C:\Users\'username'\Desktop\Test\*.lnk) do start %%v

Comment: (C:\Users\'username'\Desktop\Test*.lnk) What is Test in here? a folder or file?

Comment: It's a folder and it has the .lnk file in there. I am doing the Test'\'*.lnk - Not sure why It didn't copy over into the previous comment.

Comment: You must put a forward slash after the test 
 (C:\Users\'username'\Desktop\Test\*.lnk) 

Try this one:
for %%v in (C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Test\\*.lnk) do start %%v